# Canvas collision?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, 2d-games

Testing my game and when the user and monster collide I want the alert to pop up but no luck:

```
function die() {

  for (var i = 0; i < monster.length; i++) {
    if (user.destinationX === monster[i].destinationX && user.destinationY === monster[i].destinationY {
      alert("die");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you're experiencing is similar to the glitch in PacMan where you can occasionally walk right through a ghost without dying. Namely, expecting positions to be equal rather than checking if the distance between them is too close.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to provide a merged answer with an explanation. If you like the explanation, credit either [karaxuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265753/karaxuna) or [user2317489](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317489/user2317489).

Your problem is, as Kolink mentioned, the pacman glitch, or rather, the fact that your monsters are not just pixels - they have a size of their own. you are currently checking the origin of one object and seeing if it is exactly equal to another entity's - this will rarely, if ever, be the case. Instead, what you need to check is if the monsters have at least one common point (in other words, collision checking).

This can be trivially done by checking if the origin of one is inside the bounding box of the other, or in other words, if `monster2.x <= monster1.x <= (monster2.x+monster2.width)` and  `monster2.y <= monster1.y <= (monster2.y+monster2.height)`. The code that Arnelle Balane has provided without an explanation does that.

This is not always a good approximation, as this blindly assumes that your monster is a square. To make it a circle, you'll need to check if the centre of one monster is within a certain distance of the other centre (where distance is metric, and calculated using `sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2))`. All this is finer details, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this collision detection method. It detects collision between two objects based on overlapping of the two objects.

```
function hasCollision(object1, object2) {
  if (object1.x + object1.width < object2.x) return false;
  if (object1.x > object2.x + object2.width) return false;
  if (object1.y + object1.height < object2.y) return false;
  if (object1.y > object2.y + object2.height) return false;
  return true;
}

function die() {
  for (var i = 0; i < monster.length; i++) {
    if (hasCollision(user, monster)) {
      alert("die");
    }
  }
}
```

This collision detection considers the shape of the objects (square/rectangle) and checks whether the two objects overlap. It also need the width and height of the object to determine where the object's edges are (or you can modify it depending on what you currently have).

Comment: @Kolink Sorry. I was actually on the process of putting in some explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strict comparisons. Because frame rate may be different. And you are now detecting collision of pixels. You shall consider shapes of each object

Comment: Really? Do you click an "Add" button? Or the "Edit" button?